# TensorFlow Object Detection API - Not ALL classes are being detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

- Python: 3.7
- TF-gpu==1.15
- Quadro RTX 4000
- 8 GB VRAM, 64GB System Memory
- Pretrained model: ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config

Relatively new to the Tensorflow Object Detection API here and wanted to apply it to my own set of images. I want to teach it to discern between the top, bottom, and side view of a BGA chip (or a table if there is one that has the dimensions there) from images of what are called datasheets, which show the precise dimensions of the aforementioned components.

images/train = 565 images
images/test = 24 images

I don't understand why only the label 'top' is being recognized. Been having this problem all day and I know its not because of my csv's or tf records because I made sure those were normal after a bunch of fiddling around.

**Config File:**

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v1, configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 4
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 16
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 2500
          decay_factor: 0.9
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 4000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 24
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

**Label Map:**

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'top'
}

item {
    id: 2
    name: 'bottom'
}

item {
    id: 3
    name: 'side'
}

item {
    id: 4
    name: 'table'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, after training you are not able to see all the classes in the detection phase.
I would suggest using this script for loading the trained frozen inference and do not forget to specify the number of classes.
Best of luck!
[This is the link for the code](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py)
Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem

```
# Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
IMAGE_NAME = 'test1.jpg'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

# Path to image
PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,IMAGE_NAME)

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 6

# Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `king`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8,
    min_score_thresh=0.60)

# All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)

# Press any key to close the image
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you specify in a little more detail how I would use this? In the context of the tensorflow object detection api framework and workflow?

Comment: @anonymous there are 5 main steps:
1) change the name and direction to the pre-trained model (MODEL_NAME)
2) change the image you want to use for detection (IMAGE_NAME)
3) change the label map and use the one you have (PATH_TO_LABALES)
4) modify the number of classes (NUM_CLASSES)

The link I provided in the answer gives more details and step by step guideline.
Best of luck, recommend if you had a problem